# How to simplify this Aggregation Framework Query (with Date Formatting & Comparisons)

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I already have a working query for what I need (included below), but I can't help but feel that there must be a better way to accomplish this.  My requirements are fairly simple, but the resulting query itself is the definition of eye-bleed code.

Here's a sample document that we're iterating over (with irrelevant properties removed):

```
> db.Thing.find().limit(1).pretty()
{
    "_id": ObjectId(...),
    "created": ISODate(...),
    "updated": ISODate(...)
}
```

My requirements for the query are:

- Only match on Things where `created > updated`.
- Group on the `YYYY-MM` value of the `created` field, and reduce to a count.
- Output should look like the following:

  ```
  { "count": 93592, "month": "2014-06" },
  { "count": 81629, "month": "2014-07" },
  { "count": 126183, "month": "2014-08" },
  ...
  ```

Again, this *feels* like it should be really *simple*.  Here's my correctly functioning query that currently does this:

```
db.Thing.aggregate([
    { $project: {
        cmpDates: { $cmp: ['$created', '$updated'] },
        created: '$created'
    }},
    { $match: {
        cmpDates: { $ne: 0 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        month: {
            $concat: [
                { $substr: [ { $year: '$created' }, 0, 4 ] },
                '-',
                { $cond: [
                    { $lte: [ { $month: '$created' }, 9 ] },
                    { $concat: [
                        '0',
                        { $substr: [ { $month: '$created' }, 0, 2 ] }
                    ]},
                    { $substr: [ { $month: '$created' }, 0, 2 ] }
                ] }
            ]
        },
        _id: 0
    }},
    { $group: {
        _id: '$month',
        count: { $sum: 1 }
    }},
    { $project: {
        month: '$_id',
        count: 1,
        _id: 0
    }},
    { $sort: { month: 1 } }
]);
```

**My question:** Can this query be simplified, and if so, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.test.aggregate([
    { "$project" : { 
        "cmpDates" : { "$cmp" : ["$created", "$updated"] }, 
        "createdYear" : { "$year" : "$created" }, 
        "createdMonth" : { "$month" : "$created" } 
    } }, 
    { "$match" : { "cmpDates" { "$ne" : 0 } } },
    { "$group" : { 
        "_id" : { "y" : "$createdYear", "m" : "$createdMonth" }, 
        "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } 
    } }
])
```

The big difference is that I used a compound key for the group, so I'm grouping the pair `(year, month)` instead of constructing a string value `YYYY-MM` to accomplish the same purpose.

Comment: Yeah, relaxing the `YYYY-MM` requirements seems to help there. Also, I didn't realize you could make the `$group` _id an object like that, that's pretty handy. This query did need the `cmpDates: { $ne: 0 }` `$match` put back in, but other than that worked fine. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Whoops, that was a pretty important step. Sorry about that. I edited it in to the answer.